# Is it possible to avoid CopyPaste-function when copying and pasting charts in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, excel-charts

I want to copy a chart from one worksheet and then paste it **as picture** to another worksheet. However, to make my macro run faster, I was wondering if the following code could be applied to chart objects:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z100").value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:Z100").value
```

Answer (score 0):

No, to paste it as picture you need to do something like this to copy:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
```

And paste it as picture in your desired sheet:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
```

---

Alteratively:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.CopyPicture
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```